# Select all the data matching multiple values in the same time

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 following tables in my DB:

Statements
[image]

and Tags
[image]

When I need to select all the statements matching some tag (`$tag`), I use this SQL query:

`$select = "SELECT Statements.id, Statements.name, Statements.link FROM Statements JOIN Tags ON Statements.id = Tags.probID AND Tags.tag = '$tag'";`

Now I need to select all the statements matching a few tags in the same time. How can I do that? Should I change something in my DB?

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can match the tags using `IN` and then use `GROUP BY` to ensure that you have all of them:

```
SELECT s.id, s.name, s.link
FROM Statements s JOIN
     Tags t
     ON s.id = t.probID 
WHERE t.tag IN ('$tag1', '$tag2', '$tag3')
GROUP BY s.id, s.name, s.link
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t.tag) = 3;
```

Note:  the above example is for three tags.  The number in the `HAVING` clause needs to match the number of tags you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Gordon's answer is good. Nonetheless I want to give you an advice here: Don't make it a habit to join everything first and only then think how to get to your data.

Your original problem was simply to find statements for which **exist** a certain tag, or in other words that has a tag **in** the other table. Hence use `EXISTS` or `IN`.

```
select id, name, link
from statement
where id in (select probid from tags where tag = @tag);
```

You prabably see that this is more straight-forward than your query, because it is written like one might word the task: select data from statement where the ID is in the set of IDs tagged with @tag.

As to the additional requirement, Gordon's way is perfect: Look at the IDs in tags (i.e. group by the ID) and find the one **having** all tags. That changes above statement to:

```
select id, name, link
from statement
where id in 
(
  select probid 
  from tags 
  where tag in (@tag1, @tag2, @tag3)
  group by probid 
  having count(distinct tag) = 3
);
```